# Saltstack salt-master service start is taking too long

Tags: python, daemon, restart, salt-stack

Im in trouble with Saltstack since I started 2 diferent developments with Python using its API. Sometimes the services crashes and when I try to start them again or reboot the servers, the time it takes to start is about more than 24 hours. Logs are empty and if i start salt-master in debug mode nothing happens.

```
# dpkg -l|  grep salt
ii  salt-common                          2014.1.5+ds-1~bpo70+1
ii  salt-master                          2014.1.5+ds-1~bpo70+1
```

Note: It's happening to me in two different machines. OS Debian sid

Answer (score 0):

Whoa, 24 hours is a ridiculous amount of time to start up.

Have you added any custom grains, modules or external pillars?
Have you tried upgrading? 2014.1.10 is now out.